# Can I call SQLExecute after SQLFreeStmt without SQLPrepare?

Tags: odbc

I have the following sequence of code calls:

```
SQLPrepare
SQLExecute(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE);
SQLFreeStmt
//It works till here
SQLExecute //Now it fails.
```

Why am I required to call SQLPrepare again, I just freed the cursor. I shouldn't prepare the SQL statement again.

Answer (score 2):

The correct behaviour is that SQLPrepare/SQLExecute/SQLFreStmt(stmt, SQL_CLOSE) should allow another SQLExecute on the same stmt handle without re-preparing. You can see this as a valid state transition in the ODBC Programmers Guide. You might use this sequence if you had done a SQLPrepare(sql) and only fetched some of the rows (instead of all of them) as without the SQLFreeStmt(stmt, SQL_CLOSE) or fetching until SQL_NO_DATA was returned you'd get an invalid cursor state if you issued another SQLExecute. SQLFreeStmt(stmt, SQL_DROP) is equivalent to SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLESTMT,stmt) and frees the entire stmt handle meaning you cannot use it again at all.

Answer (score 0):

SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE) cleans up everything to do with that statement handle, take a look at the [summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709284(VS.85).aspx):

> SQLFreeStmt stops processing
>   associated with a specific statement,
>   closes any open cursors associated
>   with the statement, discards pending
>   results, or, optionally, frees all
>   resources associated with the
>   statement handle.

If you don't want to use `SQLPrepare` again you can use `SQLExecDirect` instead.

Comment: But with Oracle database, the SQLExecute works after SQLFreeStmt, so I want to know whether its a standard or not, and what is the behavior with other ODBC drivers.

Comment: SQLExecDirect is not an option, and not my question also. I just wanted to know what should be the correct behavior.